# Text align HTML & CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I've been trying to align my text and nothing seems to be happening. What is the best method to align this code, I want it centered with the shopping bag. I'm also using CSS to style.

```html
<div class="total">
  <span class="simpleCart_total">$0.00</span>
</div>
<h3>
  <center>
    <img src="shopping%20bag.png" alt="shopping bag" width="25" height="25">
  </center>
</h3>
<script src="Java.js"></script>
<p><a href="Java.js" class="simpleCart_empty"> Empty Cart</a></p>
```

Comment: can we see some more code?

Comment: `Java` !== `JavaScript`.

Comment: I'm curious about this too. As for 2017, `<center>` tag was unsupported/deprecated, and seemingly html `align=""` attribute usage is also. Meanwhile, CSS `text-align:center` is not a direct workaround because the result can be different (as it will align the "text").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.total,h3,p{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="total">
  <span class="simpleCart_total">$0.00</span>
</div>
<h3>
  <center>
    <img src="shopping%20bag.png" alt="shopping bag" width="25" height="25">
  </center>
</h3>
<script src="Java.js"></script>
<p><a href="Java.js" class="simpleCart_empty"> Empty Cart</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the content in a div and use text-align to align the text.

**HTML**

```
<div class="textCenter">
    <div class="total">
        <span class="simpleCart_total">$0.00</span>
    </div>
    <h3><center><img src="shopping%20bag.png" alt = "shopping bag" width="25" height="25"></center></h3>
    <script src="Java.js"></script>
    <p><a href="Java.js" class="simpleCart_empty"> Empty Cart</a></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.textCenter {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flex layout for this.

Try this:

```
<div class="flex_container">
    <div class="total">
        <span class="simpleCart_total">$0.00</span>
    </div>
    <h3><center><img src="shopping%20bag.png" alt = "shopping bag" 
         width="25" height="25"></center></h3>
    <script src="Java.js"></script>
    <p><a href="Java.js" class="simpleCart_empty"> Empty Cart</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex_container {
     display: flex; 
     flex-direction: column; 
     align-items: center;
}
```

This should do the job